Group records on multiple columns in snowflake
Need to group records from following below sample input data on based on state,card number,card type, origin, method of payment, sales amount so that all records belonging to same group will be present in single row.
I tried using list aggregate but on larger data set it is not working as expected.



state
card number
card type
origin
mop
sales amount




ma
123
mastercard
outside
swipe
800


ma
456
visa
inside
tap
800


ca
345
amex
outside
swipe
600



Output:



state
card number
card type
origin
mop
sales amount




ma
123,456
mastercard,visa
outside,inside
swipe,tap
800


ca
345
amex
outside
swipe
600



Tried using listagg but on large data set it is not working as expcted as grouping is based on multiple columns.

What do you mean by  I tried using list aggregate but on larger data set it is not working as expected? Please post the query you have tried and explain why it is not working.

Are you wanting to collapse the data based on state and sales amount?  You say you are grouping by everything, which makes no sense and the same data provided seems to indicate you are grouping by state and sales amount and then listagg on everything else.

WITH BASE_DATA AS
(
SELECT * FROM VALUES ('ma',123,'mastercard','outside','swipe',800)
,('ma',456,'visa','inside','tap',800)
,('ca',345,'amex','outside','swipe',600) 
TXNDATA("state","card number","card type","origin","mop","sales amount")
)
SELECT 

BASE_DATA."state"
,listagg(DISTINCT BASE_DATA."card number",',') "card number"
,listagg(DISTINCT BASE_DATA."card type",',') "card type"
,listagg(DISTINCT BASE_DATA."origin",',') "origin"
,listagg(DISTINCT BASE_DATA."mop",',') "mop"
,listagg(DISTINCT "sales amount") "sales amount"

FROM 
BASE_DATA
GROUP BY ALL
ORDER BY "state"
;


